# Can't change the css in SuiteCRM

Tags: css, smarty, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am working on SuiteCRM, and i want to change the CSS of my website in order to personalize it but there is an issue.

When i am changing the "style.css" of the SuiteP Theme, the pages aren't changing at all. Here is my question:

Does someone know how to change the css of this CRM and can help me to fix it ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

> Make sure that your active theme is "SuiteP".

You need to know that SuiteCRM store things inside "cache" folder and you are doing changes without refreshing cache files. Cache files location will be `cache/themes/SuiteP/css/style.css`. So for quick changes, you can use browser developer tools.

Moreover, if you change core style.css then empty cache directory and (hard)refresh your browser. If cache files don't exist then Suite will build new using core file.

Answer (score 1):

Like Star previously mentioned, Suite does cache the CSS.

Though, if you're not updating the SASS file, and just updating the CSS directly, your changes will be temporary for when the CRM next re-builds the CSS (I believe this is part of the Repair and Rebuild process in the admin section), your changes will be lost as the CSS file constructed from the style.scss file.

I'd recommend installing sass (via a gem or other means, however you choose), making changes to the scss then recompiling the css (or watching for changes if working locally, which I hope you are for working with Suite) when you've applied your changes.

If you still don't experience changes, try a repair and re-build or delete the cache directory and let it recompile on the next page load.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 options:

1. change core file and then delete cache contents. Refresh your page twice.
2. made changes in cache file. Make sure developer mood is off. Once you are done then copy it core file.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new subfolder CUSTOM, copy the CSS files that are under suiteP (or the current theme) into the new custom. copy the whole path with folders, even if the folders are empty. 
So the new path for the sytle.css with be /costum/theme/....../css/sytle.css 
Change the file under the custom folder. The previous answers are not correct. This is well documented under the suite CRM docs.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it doesn't work. Try next steps:

1. SuiteCRM better to use in development mode.
2. Not always the cache files deleting works for me. Better to use the tool in Admin panel - Quick Repair.
3. Sometimes good to clear browser cache (in dev mode reload a page by right clicking the refresh button).